# Xcode 8 Warning: no rule to process file of type net.daringfireball.markdown for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, markdown, x86-64, compiler-warnings

I get the above warning in Xcode 8 for a CHANGELOG.md file in my cocoapod source. How do I clear it?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. Select Project Navigator
2. Select your project
3. Select your target
4. Select Build Phases
5. Move files (in this case, CHANGLELOG.md) that you don't want the compiler to process from `Compile Sources` to `Copy Bundle Resources`

Comment: Well, this will be added next time you perform `pod install` right?

Comment: These changes will be reverted when you do a `pod update`

Comment: These changes are not reverted for me after `pod update`.